# Vue 2 Nuxt directive image source won't work

Tags: image, dynamic, nuxt.js

Can someone tell me why this does not work in Nuxt, or how to fix it. The dataset.alt attribute is simply 'image.svg'

```
el.setAttribute('src', '~/assets/images/' + el.dataset.alt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use directive binding and to require the image. Full code for reference:

```
<img src="@/assets/images/light-image.svg" v-theme-image="require('@/assets/images/dark-image.svg')" />

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'

Vue.use(VueCookies)

export const themeImage = {
    inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
        function init() {
            if ($cookies.get('theme') === 'dark') {
                el.setAttribute('src', binding.value);
            }
        }  
        init();
    },
    
}

Vue.directive('theme-image', themeImage);
```